# TileItem selectedtileColor keep shown when not in user view

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-listview, flutter-list-tile

I have this problem with `ListTile` widget. shown in this picture:
[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twdji.png)

and i don't have any clue how to prevent this from happening, `selectedTileColor` must be invisible when the user scroll.

Comment: u can use GestureDetector( onLongPressStart: ....,  onLongPressEnd : ....  ) options to do that

Comment: @JBJason Take a look at the picture attached what i try to do is to hide the tileColor when it is not in the user view anymore.

Comment: u may share ur code. *additional( try to put 2images, (1). image of what do you want (2). what result u r having

Comment: @JBJason i fixed it just wrapped the widget with container and instead of tileColor i used Color of the container